# OpenGL Environment mapping Reflection

Tags: reflection, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

my reflections are wrong. I have changed a lot of the code, but I didn't find the error. It would be great if you can help me.

Texture generation:
Code :

```cpp
m_cubeMap = new int[1];
m_cubeFB  = new int[1];

// create the cube map
glGenTextures  ( 1, m_cubeMap, 0 );
glBindTexture  ( GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, m_cubeMap[0] );

for( int i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
    glTexImage2D( GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X + i, 0, GL_RGBA, m_cubeMapSize, m_cubeMapSize, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, null );
}

glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S,     GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE );
glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T,     GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE );

glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );
glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );           


glGenFramebuffers ( 1, m_cubeFB, 0 );    
glBindFramebuffer( GL_FRAMEBUFFER, m_cubeFB[0] );
glFramebufferTexture2D   ( GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X, m_cubeMap[0], 0 );

if( LoggerConfig.ON )
    checkGlError( "InitRefCubeMap()" );

    // check status
    if( glCheckFramebufferStatus( GL_FRAMEBUFFER ) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE ) {
    if( LoggerConfig.ON )
        Log.e( "MESH", "CubeMap Framebuffer incomplete: " + glCheckFramebufferStatus( GL_FRAMEBUFFER ) );

    return;
}

// glBindRenderbuffer( GL_RENDERBUFFER,      0 );
glBindFramebuffer ( GL_FRAMEBUFFER,      0 );    
glBindTexture     ( GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, 0 );
```

Iterate through all faces ( 0 <= p_face >= 6) and draw after this:
Code :

```cpp
glFramebufferTexture2D( GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X + p_face, m_cubeMap[0], 0 );   

glClearColor( 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f );
glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );

if( LoggerConfig.ON )
    checkGlError( "DrawRefCubeMap() Activate Face " + p_face );       

float mvMatrix[] = new float[16];

switch( p_face ) {
case POSITIVE_X:
    setLookAtM( mvMatrix, 0, 
        0.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,
        1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f, 
        0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f ); 
    break;

case NEGATIVE_X:
    setLookAtM( mvMatrix, 0, 
        0.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,
       -1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f, 
        0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f ); 
    break;

case POSITIVE_Y:
    setLookAtM( mvMatrix, 0, 
        0.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,
        0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f, 
        0.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f  ); 
    break;

case NEGATIVE_Y:
    setLookAtM( mvMatrix, 0, 
        0.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,
        0.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f, 
        0.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f ); 
    break;

case POSITIVE_Z:
    setLookAtM( mvMatrix, 0, 
        0.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,
        0.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f, 
        0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f  ); 
    break;

case NEGATIVE_Z:
    setLookAtM( mvMatrix, 0, 
        0.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,
        0.0f,  0.0f, -1.0f, 
        0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f ); 
    break;

default:
    return;
};

translateM( mvMatrix, 0, -m_cubeCenter[0], -m_cubeCenter[1], -m_cubeCenter[2] );

float projMatrix[] = new float[16];
perspectiveM( projMatrix, 0, 90.0f, 1.0f, 0.01f, 100.0f );  // will the near clip plane size sufficient?

float mvpMatrix[] = new float[16];
multiplyMM( mvpMatrix, 0, projMatrix, 0, mvMatrix, 0 );

float[] MVMatrix_In = new float[16];
float[] normalMat   = new float[16];
invertM( MVMatrix_In,  0, mvMatrix,    0 );
transposeM( normalMat, 0, MVMatrix_In, 0 );

glUniformMatrix4fv( m_simplePhongShader.m_uMVMatrix,     1, false, mvMatrix,  0 ); 
glUniformMatrix4fv( m_simplePhongShader.m_uMVPMatrix,    1, false, mvpMatrix, 0 ); 
glUniformMatrix4fv( m_simplePhongShader.m_uNormalMatrix, 1, false, normalMat, 0 );
```

Fragement shader (world positions used):
Code :

```c
vec3 camRay  = normalize( v_PosW - u_CameraCenter );
vec3 wNormal = normalize( v_NormalW );
gl_FragColor = textureCube( u_CubeMap, normalize( reflect( camRay, wNormal ) ) );
```

Thank you!

*Update 1*
Screenshot: (the unreflective sphere are not reflected in the other sphere)
[image: one reflective sphere]

Comment: Could you please post screenshot of result?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have added a screenshot of two reflective spheres.

Comment: Did you try to move unreflective sphere? Also you can try to dump all faced of cube map to files and look it. You will understand where is problem in cube map creation code or in reflection code.