# Reflection of other objects in a scene in OpenGL

Tags: java, opengl, opengl-4

I'm trying to implement a OpenGL program to generate an animation of a scene composed of a central sphere, where each object in the scene (minus the central sphere) performs rotational movement around its center of mass and around the central sphere . The ball is made of polished stainless steel and features on its surface, like a mirror, the reflection of the other objects of the scene. For each object in the scene (minus the sphere) I need to do texture mapping with a different texture. Use the "environment map" approach to produce the mirror effect on the central sphere. I researched issues related to this procedure, and what I definitely can not understand is how to get the other objects on the scene reflected in that animation. A topic that I see here (which was the closest thing I have to do) and that could help me but is not answered is in the link [OpenGL Environment mapping Reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24732653/opengl-environment-mapping-reflection/44912742#44912742).

If anyone can give me any idea, I will be extremely grateful. It is a university work, where the part of object construction and rotation have been done previously. The very cruel question is how to realize the reflection of these moving objects in this central sphere.

Comment: Sorry, forget to put this information, I'm using opengl4 with java.

Comment: Your tags should reflect that information. I've removed the excess tags.

Comment: A bit of phisics: [Fresnel equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_equations#Power_or_intensity_equations) say that the angle between the source (a pixel in your object) and the normal in the surface (a plane tangent to the sphere) is the same as the normal and your eye (the camera position)

Answer (score 1):

The usual solution is to create a dynamic cube map. At each frame, render the scene from the viewpoint of the central sphere (with frustum: fov=90, aspect ratio=1, near plane=radius+epsilon) 6 times (once in each direction), and put the result into a cubemap.

Then write a pixel shader for the central sphere, which samples from this cube map.

It won't be perfect, but close.

There are other solutions for this problem, but I think this is the most easiest to develop in OpenGL.

If a more correct solution is needed, then you have to resort to other techniques, I'm afraid. Like ray tracing. If you only have simple geometries (plane, sphere), then you could write a little ray tracing engine in pixel shader or compute shader.

Comment: Sorry to ask, but would you have an example code of what was said by you?

Comment: I've implemented this, but unfortunately I cannot share it. But I think there should be some open source code which implemented this. Like in Ogre3D, or in other open source game engines.

Comment: Ahh Thank you anyway!